# IQueryable syntax for SQL not in clause

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Building my fir ASP.NET application, and have an admin page for adding or deleting items from key tables. This works fine, but I want to add a filter to the selection on the remove function so that items in use in the db cannot be deleted.

One example is two tables 1. ItemBank, 2. Questions. ItemBank has the PK and Questions is the FK, currently I have a query that retrieves the ItemBank items from ItemBank table, but I want to filter it like this SQL statement:

```
Select * 
from ItemBank 
where BankID not in (Select BankID from Questions);
```

How would I modify the below query to do this?

```
public IQueryable GetItemBank()
{
    var _db = new cs1.Models.ProductContext();
    IQueryable query = _db.ItemBank;
    return query;
}
```

Comment: Does your generated ItemBank class have a `Questions` property? So you could do something like `_db.ItemBank.Where(x => !x.Questions.Any())` ?

Comment: Chips_100 not sure I understand what your asking (new to asp.net stuff) ItemBank is it's own table and class, as is Questions. I don't currently have anything joining them together.

Answer (score 1):

If you set up the foreign keys properly you can just do `_db.ItemBank.Where(i=>!i.Questions.Any())`

Comment: Absolutely yes, nice answer!

Comment: I have primary keys assigned, but all the articles I can find for assigning foreign keys when the classes are assigned are for older versions and don't seem to work. How do I assign a foreign key?

Comment: In the Foreign key example, the "Any" at the end of the code is not accepted?